# Recreate the table in integration tests database

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade, integration-test

Let's say I created a module that has it's own setup script that should create a new table. Everything installed fine through command line and when I ran integration tests that table was there (in integration tests database).

I realized I made a mistake in my setup script, so I changed it, deleted the entry in setup_module database table, deleted the table, ran the `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command, and the table in my main table was recreated well.

The problem is that the table in my integration tests database remains unchanged. I tried deleting tmp and var folders with no luck.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

In `dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist` there is a setting responsible for clearing cache and DB on each tests execution `<const name="TESTS_CLEANUP" value="enabled"/>`. Make sure it is set to true in PHPUnit config which is used when you run tests.

Also note, that while it is more reliable to use this option (you get up-to-date environment on each run), it will delay the beginning of tests execution since Magento will be reinstalled in this case (will only affect tests DB).

Comment: It was already set to enabled, so it seems that that didn't work.

Comment: Not sure why it does not work for you, because eventually 'bin/magento setup:uninstall' is invoked when this option is enabled. Try to see locally if this method gets executed \Magento\Setup\Model\Installer::cleanupDb() and if this one is invoked $connection->query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {$dbName}"); Do you have correct DB name there?

Comment: No, that method doesn't get executed at all. Could it be because I run tests with ```phpunit -c phpunit.xml.dist``` and not with Magento's command?

Comment: There is custom integration tests bootstrap specified in phpunit.xml.dist, so it should work. Try to debug from the place where "TESTS_CLEANUP" is processed in `dev/tests/integration/framework/bootstrap.php`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It seems that the part where it drops all the tables is correct, as I stopped execution after that command and the database was empty. To me it looks like the problem is in the command that is executed after that which imports a generated sql file - tmp/sandbox-0-ea0543eebf20233936da0f99664bf3a9/setup_dump_magento_integration_tests.sql. That script contains the old database table definition. Do you maybe know how is this script generated? I cleared all the var and tmp folders.

Comment: Check if Magento can be installed from scratch and has new DB structure, if not - then, check your setup scripts.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the `TESTS_CLEANUP` setting, you can also:

- delete the row in the integration tests database:

  ```
  delete from magento_integration_tests.setup_module where module = 'MODULE_NAME';
  ```
- delete integration test tmp directory:

  ```
  rm -rf dev/tests/integration/tmp/*
  ```

The next integration test execution will trigger the install scripts for `MODULE_NAME`

Comment: Nice idea, thanks, I'll try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Issued the same problem. The following steps helps at least in my situation:

- Clear `/var/generation`
- Flush cache with `magento cache:flush`
- Remove your module entry in testing database table `setup_module`

Rerun your integration tests.

I guess magento gets something from cache in real database (e.g.) in order to build up the testing environment.